# Does ATK4 have caching support?

Tags: atk4, agiletoolkit

I've gone through the [documentation](http://book.agiletoolkit.org) on ATK4, trying to find a reference point how to handle caching - partial or full page.

Seems like there is no entry on the matter. Strange from a framework that is built for scalability. Is there a way to cache DB queries, pages, views, etc?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your question. (I'm the author of ATK4).

In my opinion, scalability and caching are two different topics and can be addressed separately. Framework approaches scalability by optimising queries and minimising load for each request and also designing approach where multiple nodes can be used to seamlessly scale your application horizontally. There is also an option to add reverse proxy to cache pages before they even hit the web server.

Agile Toolkit has support for two types of caching:

### View-level caching

As you read documentation on object render trees - framework initialise and render recursively, so if you add "caching" support to a Page level, you will be able to intercept and retrieve it's contents from cache. You can also cache views.

Here is a controller which can be used to implement caching for you:
https://github.com/agile55/viewcache

### Model level caching

Sometimes you would want to cache your model data, so instead of retrieving data from the slow database, you can quickly fetch the data from a faster source. Agile Toolkit has support for multiple model data sources, where a cache would be queried first and refreshed if it didn't contain the data. Here you can find more information or ask further questions:

http://book.agiletoolkit.org/model/core.html#using-caching

http://forum.agiletoolkit.org/t/is-setcache-implemented/62

### Other Ideas

Given the object-oriented nature of ATK4, you can probably come up with a new ways to cache data. If you have any interesting ideas, our c

Comment: Hi, model level caching is not specifically useful in the scenario I'm looking for. On the other hand, your suggestion for the view caching seems to be a half-baked solution (judging by the README) full of TODOs and FIXMEs.

Comment: There have not ben much of an interest by a current contributors to improve caching. I have only built it as a proof of concept, caching is on the long-term roadmap.

Comment: @matov, If you manage to convert my proof of concept into the workable solution, I will be happy to integrate it into the core framework.